# Accesing to a VM on Fi-lab

Tags: fiware, filab

I’m training to get familiar with the Fi-Ware Cloud service.
I can create blueprints templates and instances but I cannot access in SSH or Connect to VM display.
I have the server up and running, I can see the page “It works” of Apache.
The problem I have are:

1. With SSH I don’t know what credential I have to use, I try with my Fi-Ware credential but the server always shows me “access denied”
2. Connect to VM display it never appears the login interface.
   There is some tutorial where I can see an example of how to do it or a detailed documentation how to configure and access to in a Blueprints Instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you create a VM of Bluerpint, you should assign a keypair, that should be created previously. I suppose that you did it. Correct me if I am wrong. During the creation of the keypair, you could download en .pem file that it is used to access to the VM using ssh (ssh -i xxx.pem…).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have just created the keypair without create the certificate file then open the port 22 adding a rule. There is no way to test the virtual machine without certificates?

Comment: No, the creation of the keypair just implies the creation of a certificate, you should do it automatically or by importing any previous one (not recommended from my point of view due to it has lots of problems due to different file formats). You should download the key pair after the creation of it, due to the system does not store the public generated key after you change the page in the browser.

Comment: Ok thanks, I follow all the steps but when I try to execute:  

> ssh -i xxx.pem ….  

the system follows asking me for a password in order to access to the system. Where can I obtain the missing password that it is requesting me?

Comment: This is a typical error, the xxx.pem file has a lots permissions, in fact if you check the message that follows the execution of the ssh, it informs it to you. The solution is very easy, just restrict the permissions of the file, just execute    $chmod 600 xxx.pem    and continue with the ssh command. And then you should not have any more problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is running properly.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was already answered but I tried these solution and only had success with additional detail after Creating, Downloading and chmod-ing the keypair file:
 using 
 [user@]hostname] ssh parameter as root@Fi-lab-FloatingIPAddress , 
under root shell or
 using **sudo** command to execute ssh -i kp.pem Fi-lab-FloatingIPAddress 
Try to access without root username will results in ssh asks to password even including the keypair associated with that virtual machine. 
In other words, the keypair to access fi-lab blueprint or instances only works with root username.

Comment: Yes, it is true, we do not manage the creation of specific user inside the VM. The only accepted user to access to the VM is the root one. Keep in mind that the new images do not allow the access using password through SSH client for security reasons, only the access using keypair will be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting familiar with #Fiware Lab.
prerequisites :

- Having in the private key you generated in the fiware cloud interface in the file **fiware_rsa** (text file beginning with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----)
- Associate your server with an external IP (internet) (note you can access other instances via the one which has inet access)

> ssh -i fiware.rsa user@external-ip-address

try with root user, you should see a message advising the proper user name to use depending on the instance :

> ubuntu@front:~$ ssh -i .ssh/fiware_rsa root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
>
> Please login as the user "centos" rather than the user "root".

You can find more information here : http://fr.slideshare.net/hmunfru/setting-up-your-virtual-infrastructure-using-fi-lab-cloud

BR