# SSHing into a VM in FI-Lab with Windows

Tags: fiware, filab

I have seen this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345226/accesing-to-a-vm-on-fi-lab), but not quite the same. I'm trying to get into a VM but with a Windows machine.

- I use some SSH Client which allows me to connect to the remote server.
- I use the public key (xxx.pem) downloaded from the FI-Lab portal but it is not working.
- The client is trying to connect to the specified IP address but cannot connect to it or something else was wrong.

Any idea about what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are using PuTTY like ssh client in windows. You can download it from [www.putty.org](http://www.putty.org).

Putty does not allow to use private key file with .pem format. You should previously translate it into a .ppk file format.

Fortunately, PuTTY allows you translating this file using the PuTTYgen program (you can download it from www.putty.org as well), execute it and import the private key. If you see a successfully imported message you inly need to save the content of the .ppk file into your system and work with it in PuTTY (select the private key file for authentication).

I hope that this resolve the problem.