# newly launched centos 6.5 instance is asking for root password

Tags: filab

I've just launched an instance from image CentOS-6.5-x64 in FI-Ware FiLab.

I've created and downloaded a KeyPar.
When trying to connect for the first time - ssh -i  - it is asking for root password.

Does the image have any default root password set?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem that you have was answered in the previous link:

[Accesing to a VM on Fi-lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345226/accesing-to-a-vm-on-fi-lab/23345343#23345343)

I hope that it is the problem that you have.